# Trying to pass an array of pointers to a method and return it

Tags: c++, pointers

I was having trouble with the following code which gives syntax error. I am trying to pass an array of pointers to a method and simply return it at the end. why is this not working?

```
struct N {
    static inline int*[] eval(int*[] p){
        return p;
    };
};
```

Why can i not use this to return or use this type?

Thanks

Comment: I'd rather tag this C than C++

Comment: @CsabaToth With a function inside a struct?

Comment: why? ( im a first timer in c++)

Comment: I'm guessing you come from C# too? 
In C++, you put the squared brackets after the variable name

Comment: yes i come from java (and c#).

Thank you all for your contribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't return arrays from functions. The pointer syntax can be used however:

```
static inline int** eval(...)
```

Moreover, `p` is in the wrong place in the signature. It should be placed after the `*` and before the `[]`.

```
static inline int** eval(int* p[] )
{
    return p;
};
```

But why go to all this trouble when you can simply use a vector of `unique_ptr`:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> eval(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> const& p)
{
    return p;
}
```

Comment: IIRC `int*[]` is also an incomplete type.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that an array is just a pointer (more or less). 
Therefore, you want to pass and return a pointer to a pointer, which will change the syntax from:

```
static inline int*[] eval(int*[] p){
```

to

```
static inline int** eval(int** p){
```